# Split a dataset into multiple datasets based on a parameter

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and would like to split it into multiple datasets based on specific column values. This column is about the distance in miles (e.g from 1.34 mile to 19.92 miles) and I would like to split it every 1/4 of mile.

Do I need to use subset or split?

Comment: You need to `split`: `split(dataset, dataset$mile %/% 0.25)`

Comment: thank you all, I used this code and it did what I want. But how can I repeat a function here , I mean after splitting the data I have now hundreds of sub data sets , now I need to find the SD for each sub data set. I tried to do it myself but I think there is a useful way to find out the SD in one command than writing down hundreds commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::ntile`, however as stated in the documentation it is "*a rough rank, which breaks the input vector into n buckets.*"

```
library(dplyr)
num_bins = ceiling((19.92 - 1.34)/0.25)
df %>%
  mutate(bin = ntile(value, num_bins)) %>% 
  group_split(bin)
```